# Hide Page Navigator in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Any way to hide the Page Navigator that appears on the top of every App Maker produced page? When you create your own custom menu system that navigates the site then there is no longer a need for the page navigator. Also, the naming convention on the pages are not exactly user friendly (not allowing spaces for example) so that makes the page navigator look more like a developer tool than an end-user one. And last but not least, the page navigator is redundant if you only have one page in your app.

Comment: Have you deployed the app? In the deployed version it doesn't exists. Also, in the preview version it results to be very useful, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can show/hide page chooser by setting `?console=` URL parameter to `1` or `0` correspondingly.

But as [Morfinismo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5983596/morfinismo) noticed, most likely you are looking for creating a [deployment](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#application_publishing) which you can share with your end users, configure permissions, etc., since only you can access your `Preview` deployment.